# How to get the xpath from a item and reuse that xpath for another item

Tags: c#, xpath, webdriver, reusability

```
<li id>
<ul>
<li id="planner">
<li id="links">
<li id="trashcan">
<li id="**item70**">
    <ul>
    <li id="item74">
    <li id="item75">
    <li id="item76">
    <li id="item87">
    <li id="item88">
    <li id="item89">
    <li id="item127">
    <li id="item151">
    <li id="item159">
    <li id="item163">
    <li id="item166">
    <li id="item168">
    <li id="item169">
    <li id="item170">
    <li id="**add70**">
    </li>
  </ul>
```

This is the code i am trying to work with. The 70 from the item is generated and can be a random number. The same number is reused in the Add70 li. Also the rest of the items is also random (ie there can be more or less, even 0 items). So, to my question:

Is it anyway possible to get the xpath of the item70 to reuse with the add70 with webdriver?

I tried to search for this but could not find it.

Thanks! 
Austin

Edit:

The //[@id='item70']")) ,the number 70, is random generated. It would work for one logon but not the next login. By reuse i mean since the "item70" is related to the "add70" i would love to find the item and use it on the add

I want to reuse the "item" part and exclude the number (70). So that it could be reused on every login.

Edit2:

This is what i did to get this to work. I used the Contains(x, y) and made the xpath like this:
.//*[@id='content']/ul/li[4]/ul/li[contains(@id, 'add')]/a

Comment: What do you mean by "reuse" of an XPath expression?

Comment: You can do XPath expressions that select two or more elements with a union operator: (//li[@id='\*\*item70\*\*'])|(//li[@id='\*\*add70\*\*'])

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to parse the element to get elements from the nested unordered list if I understand it correctly.  If that is what you are trying to do then the following would work for you:

```
IWebElement myListElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[@id='item70']"));
List<IWebElement> childListElements = myListElement.FindElements(By.TagName("li")).ToList();
if (childListElements.Count > 0)
{
 // Do something Here
}
```

------ EDIT ------

Here's how I would handle the problem, now that I have a better understanding of the issue

```
IWebDriver driver; //set elsewhere
IWebElement myUnorderedList = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[@id]/ul"));  //you have an li in the example with an ID but nothing set to the ID and that's my first reference
IWebElement myAddItem = myUnorderedList.FirstOrDefault(i => i.GetAttribute("id").Contains("item"));
int thisRandomNumber = Convert.ToInt32(myAddItem.GetAttribute("id").Replace("item"));
List<IWebElement> childListElements = myAddItem.FindElement(By.TagName("li")).ToList();
if (childListElements.Count() != thisRandomNumber)
{
 //Note problem
}
```

That should get you the information you are looking for.

Comment: Actually yes. I already use that code.

My point is that the //[@id='item70']")) ,the number 70, is random generated. It would work for one logon but not the next login. Since the "item70" is related to the "add70" i would love to find the item<randomnumber> and use it on the add<randomnumber>

By reuse i mean that i want to search for the "item" part and exclude the number (70). So that it could be reused on every login.

Comment: @Austin take a look at my edits.  I haven't tested the above code but I am 95% sure that this will get you what you wanted.  Basically you just needed a lambda expression to get the correct ID

Comment: I did not get your code to work for some strange reason. VS was acting up. But after some research i did find the solution by using Contains(x, y).

like this: .//*[@id='content']/ul/li[4]/ul/li[contains(@id, 'add')]/a